# problem generating pgp keys?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I'm using RSACryptoServiceProvider I've generated public key and private key. The keys generated by it are in the following format:

Public key:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>m9bAoh2...eGNKYs=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Private key:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>m9bAo...ZAIeGNKYs=</Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
    <P>xGj/UcXs...R1lmeVQ==</P>
    <Q>yx6e18aP...GXzXIXw==</Q>
    <DP>NyxvnJ...1xAsEyQ==</DP>
    <DQ>La17Jycd...FhApEqwznQ==</DQ>
    <InverseQ>JrG7WCT...Hp3OWA==</InverseQ>
    <D>RdWsOFn....KL699Vh6HK0=</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

but using PGP Desktop i've generated keys like this -

Public key:

```
mQCNBEoOlp8BBACi/3EvBZ83ZduvG6YHu5F0P7Z3xOnpIsaPvTk0q+dnjwDUa5sU 
lEFbUZgDXSz7ZRhyiNqUOy+IG3ghPxpiKGBtldVpi33qaFCCEBiqsxRRpVCLgTUK 
HP2kH5ysrlFWkxTo 
=a4t9
```

Private key:

```
lQHgBEoOlp8BBACi/3EvBZ83ZduvG6YHu5F0P7Z3xOnpIsaPvTk0q+dnjwDUa5sU 
lEFbUZgDXSz7ZRhyiNqUOy+IG3ghPxpiKGBtldVpi33qaFCCEBiqsxRRpVCLgTUK 
waBnEitQti3XgUUEZnz/rnXcQVM0QFBe6H5x8fMDUw== 
=CVPD
```

So when I'm passing the keys generated by PGP Desktop it is able to do encryption and decryption perfectly but when im passing the keys generated by RSACryptoServiceProvider I'm not able to encrypt and decrypt?

Can anyone please tell me how to generate keys in the pattern generated by PGP?

Comment: Backrub: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/1750/2379

Answer (score 9):

using the bouncycastle c# library this is how i generate key pairs.

```
public void GenerateKey(string username, string password, string keyStoreUrl)
        {
            IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator kpg = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
            kpg.Init(new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.ValueOf(0x13), new SecureRandom(), 1024, 8));
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair kp = kpg.GenerateKeyPair();

            FileStream out1 = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}secret.asc", keyStoreUrl)).OpenWrite();
            FileStream out2 = new FileInfo(string.Format("{0}pub.asc", keyStoreUrl)).OpenWrite();

            ExportKeyPair(out1, out2, kp.Public, kp.Private, username, password.ToCharArray(), true);

        }

private static void ExportKeyPair(
            Stream secretOut,
            Stream publicOut,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey,
            AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey,
            string identity,
            char[] passPhrase,
            bool armor)
        {
            if (armor)
            {
                secretOut = new ArmoredOutputStream(secretOut);
            }

            PgpSecretKey secretKey = new PgpSecretKey(
                PgpSignature.DefaultCertification,
                PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaGeneral,
                publicKey,
                privateKey,
                DateTime.Now,
                identity,
                SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5,
                passPhrase,
                null,
                null,
                new SecureRandom()
                //                ,"BC"
                );

            secretKey.Encode(secretOut);

            secretOut.Close();

            if (armor)
            {
                publicOut = new ArmoredOutputStream(publicOut);
            }

            PgpPublicKey key = secretKey.PublicKey;

            key.Encode(publicOut);

            publicOut.Close();
        }
```

and it generate private and public keys in armored ASCII format such as.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG v1.32

mIsEShU7ywEEAKtxKTtGTyUaVxFuWBpziA2l7qDKhe6jznre3DMPuzDnN4Ax573a
7s/bPOkzkK9tEUGFw+BW6F4DkKydv8SQfSN5Vvc0RFMha8X1E8jki1oXTIPA8bKK
dg8ZewZt8+Zwpt5IPAkIydmxDhMjwd71ay3p1ypOfROFPOfc2dBPx/0JAAUTtAdo
YW1zbWFuiJwEEAECAAYFAkoVdAsACgkQEz/ESPB1tojuIQP8CjAzJx8PoIN33pxQ
AfGF+fMCZx8/m7dDBE113aiio25BCvNKOpFwye2UK4ioKN70k24pzkyi8AZO22/s
u6GL7XEiiBZLPynBxJR4A7PzvD3KNqdQUqesu9IkPFyXz3UFH3clR0hnZtZtgnbk
L9dvj5RYVuGiS3Dcf1zoLMOiCdc=
=dFfG
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Answer (score 5):

RSA and PGP are different.

What you are essentially asking is how do I run my petrol car on diesel?  The answer is you can't.

---

You should look into PGP CommandLine - this allows you to perform PGP commands from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the good methods, was faffing around the web for them since quite a while,

some correction tho...

After a call to

```
ExportKeyPair(out1, out2, kp.Public, kp.Private, username, password.ToCharArray(), true);
```

please also call

```
out1.Close();
out2.Close();
```

A sample private key generated from the above routine

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0
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=jh9t
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

thanks once again for the above methods.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.6.1.0

mIsES+Fg5wEEAJrkeNnXhQtG9ksqP6vCxxCHrdl32ud9mZUo3l82wr6hzHFXytxN
Zro/eSchYKtrWWpnWic20zy0vVdG4r2lqC7tc+OMdRHftqNi/97T/D0geU4G0zjV
PegwzjwUEflYZmzA5CdMIegelmKXHvN4mBzKhRrIz25pYZZUtvo+oATZAAUTtAhz
cGFyZWtoM4icBBABAgAGBQJL4VLXAAoJEEdeXuFsWFgEsicD/1M/CaK/Gh+zv/Lj
GauXRf5G6KyHSX4oLjn8xAZTVtPYxgJHmN5/JpQgcwqAfxtfgMehsEXG2RNehOCl
mabkk0caJJCg5epbuKoc6SnqrquTBX0Fi9+xuMyx8AFtXuXb0IygwOPWoHeT0IkM
/gy6isQjlDHfTHTsybb67BxgLb4C
=ZyOZ
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```